# Which snapshot should I use to restore data after accidental truncate?

Tags: cassandra, backup, restore

Data has been deleted from a production DB using a `TRUNCATE` command accidentally and I don't know how I should restore it. I've read about `auto_snapshot` [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503614/restore-cassandra-cluster-data-when-acccidentally-drop-table)] and fortunately this option is on. We have a bunch of snapshots (listed below) in a `snapshots` folder and we don`t know which of them we should use to restore the data.

```
root@server:/raid0/cassandra/data/raw_data_keyspace/raw_buy_hits-d5e2fc5005f411e5bc39c93f22adf770/snapshots# du
44      ./1439296902349-raw_buy_hits
44      ./1439296723590-raw_buy_hits
48      ./1439296608175-raw_buy_hits
171964  ./1439296089074-raw_buy_hits
171032  ./1439203561681
44      ./1439296856042-raw_buy_hits
44      ./1439296234966-raw_buy_hits
343224  .
```

I didn't find any mention of this problem when I read Cassandra's docs.

Which of the snapshots should we use? Should it be one of them or should we use all of them in order to restore all of the data that we lost?

Comment: http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_backup_snapshot_restore_t.html

Comment: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsBackupSnapshotRestore.html

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the latest snapshot (or the most recent snapshot before the truncate if there have been additional snapshots after the truncate).

Cassandra uses hard links when creating snapshots, which is why the sizes of those snapshots are so different.  Do get the size for each individual snapshot you have to run separate `du` commands for each of them, that way you can see what the size was at the time of the snapshot.

So rather than relying on `du` alone list the directories by date (`ls -ltr`), pick the snapshot you want to restore, and then use the `du` command to verify it is the size you're expecting.